# Java Stream collect - how to deduce type?

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I have been given a stream of words, `Stream<String> words`, and a class `Pair<String,Integer>` which realizes a simple tuple for `(someString, someInt)` with getter and setter methods for both elements called getFirst,setFirst,getSecond,setSecond.

I am now supposed to box each word of the stream into a Pair `(word, 1)`, and then use a Collector to somehow make the whole thing tell me how often each word is in the text. Now I've looked up a Collector that should let me do what I want to, and passed it as .collect(...) to the stream.
 But the whole thing is looking so complex, and the type inference and deduction and wildcards that are floating around in that topic aren't making it any easier, so that I got now no clue, just what it is I've created.

I've tried deducing it from the API, and tried all the things I could come up with, but none of it seems to match:

```
words
  .map(x -> new Pair<String,Integer>(x,1))
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
      x -> x.getFirst(),
      Collectors.reducing(
          (a,b) -> new Pair<String,Integer>(a.getFirst(), a.getSecond() + b.getSecond())
      )
   ));
```

Comment: What is the result of this stream operation supposed to be? `Map<String, Integer>`?

Comment: A collection or something of pairs, e.g. LinkedList<Pair<String,Integer>>, or just again a stream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-):

```
Collection<Pair<String, Integer>> values = words.collect(Collectors.toMap(
      Function.identity(),
      s -> new Pair<>(s, 1),
      (a, b) -> {a.setSecond(a.getSecond() + b.getSecond()); return a;}
)).values();
```

It creates a map from your stream, using provided:

- *keyMapper* - a mapping function to produce keys
- *valueMapper* -  a mapping function to produce values
- *mergeFunction* - a merge function, used to resolve collisions between values associated with the same key

So it groups your Pairs by string value to a map, and then you just call `.values()` to get a collection of Pairs

Comment: A merger function in a Map Collection... never would I have thought to look there. Though, what does the identity function there do?

Comment: @Sudix Identity function always returns the same value that was used as its argument, so in this case it is the same as `s -> s`

Comment: As we use original words as keys, we don't need to apply any mapping to them

Answer (score 1):

The easiest (though not necessarily most efficient) solution would be to group to a map and then convert the entries to pairs:

```
List<Pair<String, Integer>> pairs = words
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x, Collectors.summingInt(x -> 1)))
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .map(e -> new Pair(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: How do I know what data structure I get when using .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(...))?

Comment: This one returns a `Map<String, Integer>`.

Comment: When applying `Collectors.groupingBy(...)` with the given signature, the Collector used has the signature `Collector<? super T,A,D>` according to the API. From the context, now I see that K = String and D = Integer. But how can I link those cryptic letters to a meaning?

Comment: I'm not completely clear on what you're asking, but it sounds like you're confused about generics works. You can start reading up on it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) and post another question if you can narrow it down to a specific problem.

Comment: Okay, better formulated: In `Collectors.groupingBy(...)` as said, there's one argument of the type `Collector<? super T,A,D>`, which you fill in with `Collectors.summingInt(x -> 1)`. Now, since this is lambda stuff and all, the generics are deduced by type inference, iirc. The lambda expression `x -> 1` used however has only two types. So, it can only infer two types to  `Collector<? super T,A,D>`, and the other probably is somewhere in the implementation to be found. Now, how do I know whether it's T,A, T,D or A,D that's replaced?

Comment: Again, this topic is a bit broad for the comment section. But it you look at the signature for [`summingInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-), you'll see that it returns a `Collector<T,?,Integer>`. The middle type is hidden, as suggested in the [`Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that entering the world of collectors can be a bit frightening at the beginning, particularly if you need to deal with generic type parameters.

There are many ways to solve your problem, both with and without streams.

With streams:

```
Map<String, Pair<String, Integer>> map = words.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        word -> word, 
        word -> new Pair<>(word, 1),
        (o, n) -> {
            o.setSecond(o.getSecond() + n.getSecond()); 
            return o;
        }));

Collection<Pair<String, Integer>> result = map.values();
```

[`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) works by transforming each element of the stream into the keys (this is the 1st argument `word -> word`, which means we leave the word as is, so that it will be the key of the map), and by transforming each element of the stream into the values (this is the 2nd argument `word -> new Pair<>(word, 1)`, which means that we've found the word for the first time, so we're creating a new `Pair` instance for that word with a count of `1`).

The 3rd argument is a merge function that is to be used to merge values when the 1st argument returns a key that already belongs to the map. As maps can't have more than one entry for the same key, we need a way to *merge* the value that is already in the map for that key, with the new value produced by the 2nd argument. In this case, `o` stands for the old value and `n` for the new value. The way I merge values is by summing the counts for the word and setting the new count in the `Pair` instance that corresponds to the old value. There's no need to create a new instance of `Pair` with the word and the new count, as it's safe to accumulate the count by *mutating* the old instance of `Pair`.

Without streams:

```
Map<String, Pair<String, Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
words.forEach(word -> map.merge(
    word, 
    new Pair<>(word, 1),
    (o, n) -> {
        o.setSecond(o.getSecond() + n.getSecond()); 
        return o;
    }));

Collection<Pair<String, Integer>> result = map.values();
```

This uses [`Map.merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) and has similar semantics as the previous code.